# What is the shortest run needed for a "dropped skateboard" rider to reach 160 mph?

Tags: gravity, velocity

I just saw a great clip on the [fastest skateboarder](http://espn.go.com/action/skateboarding/story/_/id/8098465/mischo-erban-breaks-world-record-fastest-skateboard-speed) to date. He wants to reach 160 mph from a dropped board, but says his speed is limited by the roads currently available. What is the shortest run required for a "dropped skateboard" rider to reach 160 mph? Is it even possible?

Comment: No, his speed is limited by air resistance. Straight down he'll hit 120 mph.

Comment: If he's skating in a vacuum, will he reach 160 mph before he asphyxiates? Feel free to assume a spherical skateboarder.

Comment: That should be a *uniform*, spherical skateboarder to keep things as simple as possible...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - 120mph is for a spread-eagled skydiver. A head down, arms back long boarder pose might do 160mph

Comment: @Martin: At that point you're [not skateboarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_luge).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I mean the long skateboards that you stand up on. The pose is like speed skating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted above the general value for  terminal velocity is around 120mph. But this is for skydivers in a stable arms spreadeagle pose.  [Speed skiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_skiing) on steep hills with streamlined clothing reach 156mph (251km/h).

Presumably if you had low enough rolling friction, a long and smooth enough road (and sufficient levels of stupid) you could do this on wheels

If you can ignore mechanical friction then the speed limit only depends on aerodynamics, ie only on your shape (assuming air at standard temperature and pressure) so with enough time you could achieve this on a hill of any slope. A steeper  slope merely gives you more power to reduce the effect of rolling friction in the wheels.